# JSF 2 - How To Preserve XML Entity Definitions in HTML output?

Tags: xml, jsf, entity, facelets, doctype

I'm working on a JSF 2 web application. If I define a facelet that begins as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.2//EN"
"http://www.openmobilealliance.org/tech/DTD/xhtml-mobile12.dtd"[
    <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;"> 
    <!ENTITY pound "&#163;"> 
]>
<html 
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<h:head>
```

When rendered as HTML the entity definitions have been removed. Is there a way to preserve them if I really want them included in the output markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you can write a new renderer also, but i had a similar problem with responding an XML result.

In my case i grabbed the HttpOutputStream in the Backing Bean and wrote the XML. Maybe if you skip the close and ctx.responseComplete() from my example, JSF normally writes his response in the stream.

```
FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

final HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse)ctx.getExternalContext().getResponse();
resp.getOutputStream().write(xml.getBytes());
resp.getOutputStream().flush();
resp.getOutputStream().close();

ctx.responseComplete();
```